# Switch button not showing up in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-switch, android-togglebutton

I have a Switch that I placed into my ActionBar, but it doesn't seem to show up and I don't see why. This was my attempt:

create_post_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".CreatePost">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/toggle_test"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/send_post"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Send"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

CreatePost.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_post_menu, menu);
    // Get the action view used in your toggleservice item
    final MenuItem toggleservice = menu.findItem(R.id.toggle_test);
    final Switch actionView = (Switch) toggleservice.getActionView();
    actionView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // Start or stop your Service
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I tried to instantiate the Switch to see if I can set a listener to see if you click on or off for the switch but I can't seem to instantiate it as I get an error trying to create the `actionView` variable in CreatePost.java. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your logacat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your are getting error because your actionView is null. change your Switch menu code

```
<item
     android:id="@+id/toggle_test"
     android:title=""
     app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
     android:orderInCategory="1"
     android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch" />
```

to `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"` look carefully it would be `app` not `android` like this...

```
<item
      android:id="@+id/toggle_test"
      android:title=""
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch" />
```

and now change your java code like this

```
final MenuItem toggleservice = menu.findItem(R.id.toggle_test);
Switch actionView=(Switch) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(toggleservice );
actionView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // Start or stop your Service
    }
});
```

Comment: When I try to implement your code, I get an error saying: `Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.View android.view.MenuItem.getActionView()' on a null`. Seems like my Switch is not being instantiated.. any idea why?

Comment: did you use this code `MenuItemCompat.getActionView(toggleservice )` .. your error say `.....MenuItem.getActionView()` that means you are still using  this `toggleservice.getActionView()`

Comment: I was using the code you provided but I got an error saying that I could not use `getActionView()` with the `toggleService` variable